# Best way to dock subset of protein PDB and definition of a ligand

Tags: pdb, docking, 3d-structure, structural-biology

I have extracted residue 45 to 88 from a PDB file (**[2YRQ](https://www.rcsb.org/structure/2yrq)**).
With that I have a new smaller PDB file. Let's call it 45_88.pdb
And I want to dock it to some other full protein.

My question is what's the best way to dock it. I'm considering **[Autodock Vina](http://vina.scripps.edu)**.
But I'm not sure if it's appropriate since it is for ligand-protein docking.

What's the definition of a ligand? Can a protein with only 42 residues be considered a ligand?

Comment: I would advise using the term `peptide` more so than ligand, which also includes, and generally is used to refer to, `small molecules`.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from @pippo1980, converted from comment:

https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jctc.9b01208 Comprehensive Evaluation of Fourteen Docking Programs on Protein–Peptide Complexes